# T-SQL Over Partition Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to eliminate rows from this sql. The multiples are due to the Contact table in the inner join. Some PID's have multiple rows for a ContactType. For example PID '123' may have 2 rows for 'EPH' but the numbers are different. We just want to return the first one. I think I should be using a Over Partition but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

```
SELECT  UPPER(p.LastName) AS 'Last Name'
              ,UPPER(p.FirstName) AS 'First Name'
              ,UPPER(p.NickName) AS 'Nick Name'
              ,p.CC AS 'Cost Center ID'
              ,UPPER(cc.DBA) AS 'Cost Center'
              ,UPPER(mbs.Title) AS 'Title'
              ,UPPER(a.City) AS 'City'
              ,UPPER(s.Code) AS 'State'
              ,a.ZipCode AS 'Zip Code'
              ,c1.Number AS 'Home Number'
              ,c2.Number AS 'Personal Cell'
              ,c3.Number AS 'Work Cell'
              ,p.PID

FROM Personnel p WITH (NOLOCK)
       JOIN mbs_Employee mbs WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON mbs.PID = p.PID
       JOIN CostCenter cc WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON cc.CostCenterCode = p.CC
       JOIN Address a WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON a.PID = p.PID
       JOIN ref_State s WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON s.StateId = a.StateId
       LEFT JOIN Contact c1 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c1.PID = p.PID
                     AND c1.ContactType = 'EHP'
       LEFT JOIN Contact c2 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c2.PID = p.PID
                     AND c2.ContactType = 'EOT'
       LEFT JOIN Contact c3 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c3.PID = p.PID
                     AND c3.ContactType = 'EWC'
WHERE Termination IS NULL
```

UPDATE
I ended up changing the joins with Contact to

```
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT  Number
    ,PID
    ,ContactType
FROM    ( SELECT    Number
                    ,PID
                    ,ContactType
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ContactType ORDER BY Number DESC ) AS rn
            FROM      Contact
                            ) c3
            WHERE   c3.rn = 1
                  ) r3 ON r3.PID = p.PID
AND r3.ContactType = 'EWC'
```

Comment: `select row_number() over (partition by p.PID order  by 1) r` ... `where r = 1`

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, please consider deleting it or answering your own question and accept the answer. this way people will know that the problem is solved.